# ¿Como incluir en un html otro html con un archivo js unido a él?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un html que incluye dentro de él otro html y que este último utiliza un archivo .js . Al lanzar el html en http://127.0.0.1:5000/, solo coge el html en sí pero no los javascripts unidos a éste. Sabeis alguna forma de que cargue todos los archivos (el html y el js incluido)?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. ¿Nos dices como incluyes el archivo HTML?

Answer (score 1):

incluir html en otro html no se puede, hay varias formas de hacer lo que necesita:

- usar php que es el mas sencillo u otro lenguaje q trabaje en servidor
- por js usando jquery, es importante resaltar el hecho de que pueden haber complicaciones por cross site origin si la pagina es de otro sitio web

  `$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#su-elemento').load('directorio/archivo.html');
   });`
- iframe directo de html que tambien presenta complicaciones por cross site origin si la pagina es de otro sitio web y carga web completas

  `<iframe src="supagina.html"></iframe>`